# Perl: Erase empty lines and save in a new file

Tags: perl, counter, erase, string

I am trying to write a script which will count and erase empty lines from a file and save the changes in a new file:

```
if (@ARGV != 2) {
  print "Usage: $0 infile outfile\n";
  exit;
}
$infile = @ARGV[0];
$outfile = @ARGV[1];
open($old, "<$infile");
open($new, ">$outfile");
@mass = <$old>;
foreach $newc(@mass) {
    $counter++;
    if ($_ =~ /^$/) {
        print "blank line found in $old at line number $counter\n";
        print $new;
    }
}
close($new);
close($old);
```

But it's not working.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is the question? What is going wrong?

Comment: @ARGV[0] Works well, ive tested it out in other script before. My problem is that I can't remove these empty lines and Spaces of input file

Comment: `@array[$index]` works, but it is not correct style. `@array[...]` is meant to return multiple indexes, like `my @slice = @array[1,2,3,4,5]`. Notice that the sigils match, `@slice` and `@array` start with the same character. This is why it is better to write `my $item = $array[0]` instead of `my $item = @array[0];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

@ARGV == 2 or die "Usage: $0 infile outfile\n";

open my $fhIN,  '<', $ARGV[0] or die $!;
open my $fhOUT, '>', $ARGV[1] or die $!;

while (<$fhIN>) {
    if (/\S/) {
        print $fhOUT $_;
    }
    else {
        print "Blank at line $.\n";
    }
}
```

As [amon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1521179/amon) showed, you can iterate over your file's lines without first reading them into an array.  This script also takes advantage of `$.`, which contains the file's current line number.  The regex `/\S/` checks for any non-whitespace characters in the line, as this indicates a non-blank line.  If `/\S/` is true, it writes the line to `outfile`, else it prints the blank-line notification.

The file handles are lexically scoped in [the three-argument form of `open`](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1582932&seqNum=2) (the preferred method), so the files will automatically `close` at the script's end.

---

You can even go a step further and take advantage of STDIN, STDOUT and STDERR for maximum flexibility and usefulness.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    if (/\S/) {
        print;
    }
    else {
        print STDERRR "Blank at line $.\n";
    }
}
```

Then just use

```
script.pl file.in >file.out
```

instead of

```
script.pl file.in file.out
```

but it also allows you to do stuff like

```
prog1 | script.pl | prog2
```

Comment: Have to accept that this is working much better than the others, I had some bug with other codes which are posted here! Thanks

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I added a section to your answer showing how to simplify the program and make it more powerful and behave more like other programs at the same time.

Comment: @ikegami - Mind?  No, not at all.  I always appreciate your additions and modifications.  I know it'll be good for the OP and I benefit, too.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't use `$newc` in your loop and you print only the blank lines

```
foreach $newc (@mass) {
    $counter++;
    if ($newc =~ /^$/) {
        print "blank line found in $old at line number $counter\n";
    } else {
        print $new $newc;
    }
}
```

As already noted in the comments, use `$ARGV[0]` and `$ARGV[1]`. `$ARGV[0]` is the first value of `@ARGV`, whereas `@ARGV[0]` is a slice. See [Slices](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

The lines in `@mass` still contain a trailing newline. Either account for that in your regex, or chomp the values.

I would code the loop like

```
while (<$old>) {
  chomp;
  say {$new} $_ if length;
}
```

Also, test the return value of open:

```
open my $old, "<", $infile or die qq(Can't open "$infile": $!);
```

The whole code as a one-liner:

```
perl -nE'chomp; say if length' infile.txt >outfile.txt
```

or

```
perl -nE'chomp; if(length){say}else{say STDERR "blank on line $."}' infile.txt >outfile.txt
```

(`$.` is the current input line number.)

Comment: He does account. `/^$/` (unlike `/^\z/`) will match `"\n"`.

Comment: btw, `chomp` can be replaced by `-l`, since `-nl` chomps. (Same goes for `-pl`.)

Answer (score -2):

Your script should be like this:

```
if (@ARGV != 2) {
  print "Usage: $0 infile outfile\n";
  exit;
}
$infile = $ARGV[0];
$outfile = $ARGV[1];
open $old, "<", $infile;
open $new, ">", $outfile;
@mass = <$old>;
$counter = 0;
foreach $newc (@mass) {
    $counter++;
    if ($newc =~ /^$/) {
        print "blank line found in $infile at line number $counter\n";
    } else { # print in the new file when not an empty line!
        print $new $newc;
    }
}
close($new);
close($old);
```

Comment: why the down vote?  the code works!  someone wants to promote their answer??

Comment: Reasons for downvote: (1) The answer contains almost no explanation. (2) It uses a somewhat outdated coding style; slightly off from current best practices: (2.1) global variables (2.2) forgetting the return value of `open`. (3) The solution still uses *O(n)* memory, where *O(1)* is enough.

Comment: The point of not using all the best practices is of course to modify his code minimally so he can see where the modifications are

Comment: @amon The difference between this and your answer is, the OP can see what he has done wrong. Whereas in your answer, he just learns how *you* would do it.

Answer (score -2):

```
if (@ARGV != 2) {
  print "Usage: $0 infile outfile\n";
  exit;
}

$infile = $ARGV[0];
$outfile = $ARGV[1];
open(OLD, "<$infile");
open(NEW, ">$outfile");
while ($line = <OLD>) {
    print NEW $line unless ($line =~ /^$/);
}
close(NEW);
close(OLD);
```

Comment: Reasons for downvote: (1) The answer contains *no* explanation. (2) It uses horrid and outdated coding style; nowhere near current best practices: (2.1) global variables (2.2) bareword filehandles (2.3) two-arg form of `open` (2.4) forgetting the return value of `open`.

Comment: This orignal question was for a quick and dirty perl script. This isn't a production app its a quick tool to do a task. Following coding practices on a 10 line script is just silly IMO. To each their own.

Comment: @amon When I apply these rules to your answer, I must downvote your answer as well.

Comment: @OlafDietsche then please, by all means, do.

Comment: @amon No, I don't. Because *my* criteria is not some superficial coding style or best practice, which is important too, but whether an answer is *useful*. (Look at the downvote arrow, when you hover over it).

Comment: Always `use strict; use warnings;`, regardless whether it's "...a quick and dirty perl script" or not.

Comment: Who cares if it's a throwaway? First, the OP appears to be someone trying to learn Perl. Second, it's just as easy to do it right.